# Is there a formula that will return a list of all the sheet names in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google spreadsheet containing 20 sheets.

Is it possible to create a formula that returns a current list of all the sheet names in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a widely used script for this:

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

Following that, you refer to it by placing `=sheetnames()` in a cell.

*PS: It is a very useful way when you make a range out of it and use it in formulas.*

References

- [Google Developers > **Google Apps Script** > Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Answer (score 13):

Here's a more concise version which is easy to achieve because the return type of `getSheets` is `Sheet[]`.

```
function sheetnames() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()
    .map(s => s.getName())
  ;
}
```

NOTE: This requires to use the Google Apps Script runtime (Chrome V8). It's the default runtime for new projects.

References

- [Google Developers > **Google Apps Script** > Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: I tried using this script but it throwing below errors:

[3, 16] Cannot find name 'SpreadsheetApp'.
[3, 7] Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
[2, 7] Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
[1, 10] No function of name 'main' found. Ensure the function exists and is not nested in anything.

Comment: I´m having tha same problem as described by @Pawan: "Cannot find name 'SpreadsheetApp'."
"Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable." Someone can help us?

Comment: @Pawan: It looks that you are trying to use code for Google Apps Script in Office Scripts, unfortunatelly that isn't possible.